# Expression expected for logical OR operator to boolean in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm having trouble seeing why this error is being generated as the code looks perfectly fine.

Reactjs component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuth: ||state.auth.uid
});
```

Error is on the || operator. Read up on other answers and all I can find is webstorm and even so, nothing reolves this issue in my case.

I'm using ES6 syntax, babel & eslint airbnb rules if that helps.

**Update: Typo (|| to !!)**

Comment: Where's the left-side operand?

Comment: `||` needs a left and a right hand operand. You are only providing the right-hand operand.

Comment: Are you trying to convert to a boolean? Then its `!!` instead of `||`.

Comment: `isAuth: state.auth.uid && true` would work too

Comment: Thanks everyone, my bad. Typo. @CRice error is now fixed

Comment: @cala Voting to close as typographical error

Comment: @JonasW. that works too! great

Comment: Extra question - would it be more proficient to use the && true or does it do the exact same thing?

Comment: Doesnt matter. Just a question of readability

Comment: Note there is a slight difference between `!!state.auth.uid` and `state.auth.uid && true`, which is that in the latter case if `state.auth.uid` is falsy (eg: `0` or `""`), then it will use that value, and not the boolean `false`.

Comment: @CRice good point to note!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuth: state.auth.uid || 0
});
```

I'm just assuming, you want to store either `state.auth.uid` if its valid or 0/false if its not, in `isAuth`.

Hope that serves your requirement.